# Visual Studio 2010 cannot add Newtonsoft.Json Library

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I've got a Problem with Visual Studio 2010 and the `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

A few hours ago nothing was wrong with my project, but now it throws this error

> The type or namespace name 'NewtonSoft "could not be found. (Missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

--I just saw that the Reference was deleted and i can't re-add the `NewtonSoft.Json` library.

Comment: What do you mean you can't readd it?  Are you missing the path to the assembly?  Do you need to update the nuget reference?

Comment: What is the error when you try to add it again

Comment: Have you tried using the NuGet package manager to install this?

Comment: In order to "re-add" a nuget reference, you need to remove it from the  packages.config file.  Once the reference there is gone, installing again it from nuget will work.

Comment: The title is incorrect.  VS isn't ignoring anything.

Comment: @verdesrobert Thats also a problem there is no error that is being displayed.

Comment: @UrKll Can you post your project .csproj file content?
  You can open it with Notepad or an XML file reader

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package manager console to remove the package, if you're having trouble getting NuGet to uninstall or reinstall it using the GUI:

```
Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Be sure you've selected the right target project from the dropdown at the top of the console if your solution contains several projects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the .NET framework version your project targets is the same or higher than the one your Json.NET nuget package requires.